# JSON data not showing in highstock Candlestick chart using PHP & MYSQL

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I'm trying to create a [highstock](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts)'s [candlestick chart](http://highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick) using php and mySQL.

this is my code so far, really appreciate if anyone can help me with this:

This my code for retrieving data from mySQL database and convert it to JSON format (datachart.php):

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error ());
$db = mysql_select_db ("b27sim") or die (mysql_error ());

$result=mysql_query ("SELECT date, open, high, low, close FROM mb27_daily") or die (mysql_error ());

$data = array();
$count = 0;
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

  $newdate = strtotime($row['date']) * 1000; 
  $data[] = array( $newdate, (float)$row['open'], (float)$row['high'], (float)$row['low'], (float)$row['close']);
  $count++;
}   
echo json_encode($data);
```

This is the result from datachart.php:

> [[1350252000000,369.72,371.02,368.09,370.22],[1349820000000,366.58,369.13,364.92,368.92],[1349733600000,367.38,369.93,366.82,368.64],[1349388000000,367.28,371.85,367.2,369.9],[1349301600000,362.75,366.24,362.22,365.61],[1349215200000,363.34,363.54,361.27,362.27],[1349128800000,360.79,362.73,360.33,361.77],[1349042400000,360.75,360.75,357.94,359.46],[1348783200000,360.62,362.69,359.84,362.5],[1348696800000,356.39,361.01,355.32,359.34],[1348524000000,358,360.39,356.34,359.7],[1348437600000,357.96,360.99,355.92,356.89],[1348178400000,359.27,360.53,356.93,360.53],[1348092000000,358.74,359.31,356.51,358.01],[1348005600000,357.97,361.82,357.24,359.86],[1347919200000,359.8,360.34,356.78,358.5],[1233010800000,119.28,122.42,119.28,121.91]]

And this is my javascript code inside index.htm:

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('datachart.php', function(data) {

    // create the chart
    chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart : {
            renderTo : 'container',
        },

        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 1
        },

        title : {
            text : 'IB27 Price'
        },

        series : [{
            type : 'candlestick',
            name : '',
            data : data,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            },
            dataGrouping : {
                units : [
                    ['week', // unit name
                    [1] // allowed multiples
                ], [
                    'month', 
                    [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]]
                ]
            }
        }]
    });
    });
});
```

and this is my div calling the container:

```
<div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 500px"></div>
```

and this is the result:
I got has not graph inside, but showing the timeline at the bottom, the date range on right top, etc.

Appreciate you guys help on this as I've been banging my head for the last 4 hours because of this... :)

Thanks,
Raz

Comment: you might want to change your db connectivity details after posting this (and by the looks of it, you might've wanted to do that already before)

Answer (score 1):

Your data should be sorted by x (timestamps), ascending.

Comment: This is the right answer.  Probably for any chart, I just experienced this with the highstock chart.  thank you...